# Looping through and appending a list of names

Tags: python, for-loop, python-3.x

I'm writing a program that keeps asking the user to enter names until the word END is entered, 
at which point it prints out the list of names.

The code:

```
import getpass
import time
import sys
print("Welcome " + getpass.getuser() + "...")
time.sleep(0.25)
print("This program, powered by Python, it will ask you to enter names...")
time.sleep(0.5)
print("...once you have finished, enter END to print off your list")
names = []
for i in names:
    name = input("Please enter a name: ")
    if name == "END":
        print(names)
        sys.exit()
    names.append(name)
```

The issue is that the program exits before it even attempts to do the for loop.

Why is this happening and how should I tackle it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It occurs because the variable `names` is empty *thus there's nothing to iterate over*

So use a while loop instead:

```
while True:
    name = input("Please enter a name: ")
    if name == "END":
        print(names)
        break   
    names.append(name)
```

Note: To exit a loop use `break` instead of `sys.exit()` after all:
*simple is better than complex*

Answer (score 3):

To get a list of names:

**Python 3+**:

```
names = list(iter(lambda: input('Enter name (leave blank to finish): '), ''))
```

**Python 2.7+**

```
names = list(iter(lambda: raw_input('Enter name (leave blank to finish): '), ''))
```

**Usage:**

```
>>> names = list(iter(lambda: input('Enter name (leave blank to finish): '), ''))
Enter name (leave blank to finish): bob
Enter name (leave blank to finish): cindy
Enter name (leave blank to finish): 
>>> names
['bob', 'cindy']
```

**Implement in your own code:**

```
import getpass
import time
import sys
print("Welcome " + getpass.getuser() + "...")
time.sleep(0.25)
print("This program, powered by Python, it will ask you to enter names...")
time.sleep(0.5)
print("...once you have finished, enter END to print off your list")
print(list(iter(lambda: input('Enter name (END to finish): '), 'END')))
```

**Demonstration:**

```
>>> 
Welcome inbar...
This program, powered by Python, it will ask you to enter names...
...once you have finished, enter END to print off your list
Enter name (END to finish): abe
Enter name (END to finish): bob
Enter name (END to finish): END
['abe', 'bob']
```

Answer (score 2):

`names` is a empty list.

```
names = []
```

Because it have no item, iterating it has no effect.

---

```
>>> names = []
>>> for name in names:
...     print(name)
...
>>> names = ['tim', 'timmy']
>>> for name in names:
...     print(name)
...
tim
timmy
>>>
```